# Using fcntl() in C

Tags: c

I want to write a programm for removing the first number of a file and adding a number at the beginning of the same file. This request should be done for many clients who try to do these simultaneously. I try to solve the problem but I stuck. Could anyone help me?

```
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h> 
#include<sys/stat.h>


int main()
{
  int a[100];
  a[0]=1;
  a[1]=4;
  int c=2;
  struct flock fl;
  int operatiune;
  printf("%s\n","1-Add,0-delete");
  scanf("%d",&operatiune);
  int fd=open("Stiva.txt",O_RDWR);
  if(operatiune==1)
  {
    int nr;
    printf("\n%s\n","Introdu numarul pe care vrei sa il adaugi");
    scanf("%d",&nr);
    if(fcntl(fd,F_SETLKW,&fl)>0){
      fl.l_type=F_UNLCK;
      fl.l_whence=SEEK_SET;
      fl.l_start=0;    
      fl.l_len=0;
      fl.l_pid=getpid();
      c++;
      for(int i=c;i>=0;i--)
         a[i]=a[i-1];
      a[0]=nr;
      fwrite(a,1,c,fd);
    }
  }
  return 0; 
 }
```

Firstly I tried to read a number and to be able to add it to the file.And to be able to do it at the same time from more terminals. But It doesn;t to anything!Thank you very much!

Comment: Please edit your code to english. Also, you should check the return of `fopen`and don't forget to `fclose`your file. Don't forget to print an error when `fcntl`fails, for example using `perror`

Comment: `fwrite(a,1,c,fd);` to an `int` file descriptor is wrong.  `fwrite()` writes to a `FILE *`.

Comment: I would use a FIFO queue to store the requests from the clients as they come in. Then, have a loop that checks periodically whether there is a new request available in the queue. Remove this request and do the operation on your file.

Comment: @Badda I thought the code is written in `C`.

Comment: **Always a bug:** not checking the return value from `scanf` and friends.

Comment: @GauravPathak I don't get what you are trying to say ?

Comment: @Badda I was just kidding..!!